# Unable to Install firefox on ubuntu 14.04 with firebug

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I have ubuntu with 14.04, but the firefox version is 28.0. I am not able to install firebug for that version.

So decided to update firefox but did not get any success.

Tried

> sudo apt-get update

also tried Update Manager

Please help.

Comment: Try F12, Tools > Web Developer or Right Click > Inspect Element (Q). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I can inspect elements with web developer tool. But I want firebug..

Comment: Could you add more info: how are you trying to install it and what's the error message you got?

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade command I have tried. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion#Security-testing_packages.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you; I've included the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox` and this should install firefox version 32.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Does not update your software. That command only updates the package list so your system will know what software versions are the newest. You must type the following command to *actually* apply the updates:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox
```

Then restart firefox and go to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=ss to install firebug.

Alternatively, you can use the command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But the updates from a dist-upgrade can cause instability issues that may need to be worked out so if you are working on a project for school or work, you might want to hold off on that command until you are done with your important projects and have the time to work out any issues that may arise.

Comment: did not worked :(

Comment: I have not tried sudo apt-get dist-upgrade , coz you are saying it will cause some problem..as I am want this for my project work

Comment: @ashwini then you can run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox` and it should install the latest version of firefox which is version 32.

Comment: @Ashwini if the answer works for you, please click the icon on the left to mark your question as answered. Otherwise please post any errors. Thanks!